# Pulling the where from Google Calendar API

Tags: php, zend-framework, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to pull the where attribute out of an Event using the Zend GData Framework with php. Does anyone know the proper format to get that attribute?

```
$eventFeed = $gdataCal->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
foreach ($eventFeed as $event) {
 $start = $event->when[0]->startTime;
 $end = $event->when[0]->endTime;
 $where = $event->where[0]->valueString;  //--this guy is the problem
 $title = $event->title->text;
 $id = $event->id;
 $content = $event->content->text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the proper format already:

```
$where = $event->where[0]->valueString;
```

This works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you have the *correct* syntax for the where parameter as long as it is the first item in the array. In your code you don't really show what you are doing with the code, I mean you are looping through the events, setting variables, then moving to the next item and over writting the variables to the next event, without doing anything to the previous event (sorry if you cut you code down for the example).

So you could use `print_r` to print the array to screen and see what is in there, but it won't be very clear specially if you are not used to looking through zend arrays:

The other thing is to loop through the where array and print the bit you want to see, see if there is more than one where item for the event:

```
$eventFeed = $gdataCal->getCalendarEventFeed($query);
foreach ($eventFeed as $event) 
{
    $start = $event->when[0]->startTime;
    $end = $event->when[0]->endTime;
    // test 1: see whats in the array:
    print_r($event->where[0]);
    // test 2: loop through the where array and see what you get:
    foreach ($event->where as $val)
    {
        $where = $val->valueString;
        echo $where.'<br />';
    }
    $title = $event->title->text;
    $id = $event->id;
    $content = $event->content->text;
}
```